# Xcode 4.5 not creating xib file

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.5, xib

I have created SimpleView based application, in which i want to add new file with `.xib` interface but when i add new file then `Objective-C class` and then subclass of `UITableViewCell` there option of `with xib for user interface` is disabled i also want to add xib..

How to add new files with `.xib` interface ?

Here are screenshots..
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
**Thanks for reading..**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why this is disabled. And I couldn't remembered that was it enable in previous versions of xcode.

But you can add `xib` for custom cell as described in [**`this tutorial`**.](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/how-to-add-a-custom-uitableviewcell-to-a-xib-file-objective-c/)

Here is the quick steps

1. Create a simple view XIB
2. Drag a table view cell into the XIB from the object browser in the bottom right corner
3. Delete the superfluous view

Answer (score 7):

Only certain classes such as `UIViewController` will have the nib option enabled. `UITableViewCell` is **not** one of these classes.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure also that "iOS" is selected, and not "OSX" when choosing a template for your new file.  When "OSX" is selected, the option was disabled in my project.

Answer (score 0):

for UITableViewCell you will not have xib for that we have add an empty view by selecting userinterface while adding new file. Then drag and drop uitableview cell.